# Change Launcher without starting it

Tags: samsung-nexus-s, launcher, go-launcher-ex

I have installed GO Launcher and GO Locker. Now, when I updated them, they got an error.

The problem is that, nothing shows up when I press unlock button (I have Nexus S). So, there's nothing I can do with the phone. There's no display at all. I know the phone is running in the background. I get the tone when I get a message.

I tried to call my phone hoping it'd get unlocked for answering that call. It did get unlocked, but when I answered the call, it got locked again. No display again. But, when the phone was still ringing, I got a Force Close dialog for GO Launcher EX ( not for GO Locker ).

I restarted the phone (removed the battery). When the phone started, it was locked (using the default Android locker). When I try to unlock it, the screen doesn't work.

Now, I am unable to use my phone. The first thing that I'd like to do is change the launcher without starting the phone itself. Is that possible?

Or do I have to restore the factory settings? If I can restore factory settings, I must be able to do so without starting the phone? Can we do that? In Nokia, we can do that by pressing some key combination and restarting the phone. Does that apply here too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try installing a different launcher app via the Android Market web interface.

1. On your PC go to [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store) and sign in with the same Google account as on your phone.
2. Find any Home replacement app. Click on the <kbd>Install</kbd> button to send the app directly to your phone (if you have several Android devices you will need to select the phone.)
3. After a few minutes try unlocking your phone. It should ask you to select a launcher app, so pick the one you just installed, or the default one.

Comment: This is good solution. But, fortunately, my phone somehow worked and I didn't need to resort to any of the solutions. Thank you anyway. I consider this to be the best way to go, if anyone gets stuck with this problem. So, I accept this answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you can connect to the device with adb ([Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)) you can open a command line and do:

`adb uninstall com.gau.go.launcherex`
`adb uninstall com.jiubang.goscreenlock`

those will remove both Go Launcher EX and GoLocker. If you can't you may have to do a factory reset, which will remove all the apps and data on the device (but to even do that you need to get to the settings application)

Comment: I believe you can do a factory reset from the Recovery.