# I deleted my only launcher

Tags: 2.2-froyo, launcher, unbricking, lg-optimus-one

I deleted my only launcher and now I cannot open settings to set to debug mode in order to use ADB or similar to install a new launcher. I can't open the Play store, can't open anything except those that use voice commands: e-mail, text, phone, maps, navigation, and note to self.

Oh, and it only boots in safe mode.

It's an LG Optimus T.

How do I put a launcher back on this phone?

Comment: Closely related: [Change Launcher without starting it](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15493/change-launcher-without-starting-it)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I figured this out only after months of being without most of my phone's functionality and taking it to a 3rd-party repair place that declared it "unrepairable".

It is stupidly easy:

1. Download an apk of your home launcher (I got one from here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/archive/index.php/t-1125331.html )
2. E-mail it to yourself
3. Use voice commands to send yourself a test e-mail. If you don't have gmail set up, then it will give you the screens you need for configuration.
4. E-mail the apk to yourself. When you check your gmail on your phone you should see an "install" button next to the attachment name. Install it and enjoy your new old phone.

Comment: Couldn't you install a new launcher from play.google.com ?

Comment: @beth , couldn't you open play.google.com in your computer and pick one launcher and click install on your computer which magically installs the launcher in your phone.

Comment: Nope. I tried it and the installer was apparently gone too.

Comment: Could you also have installed the apk using adb?

Comment: @TimScarborough They haven't got ADB active, and can't open the settings to activate it.  So in this case, no.

Answer (score 2):

Download the Launcher .apk file (just Google your "demand launcher name" and plus "apk"), save it to your friend's phone, and send it to your phone via Bluetooth.  After you recieve the .apk file just click whatever option that directs you to INSTALL the file.  If Bluetooth is off, ask your friend to call your phone; when the dialer window pops up you can see a "make another call" button.  Click it and you will see the shortcut bar for Bluetooth appear.

Comment: How is this different than the accepted answer?

Comment: It doesn't use voice commands.  I know I have those disabled entirely on my phone.

Comment: I didn't have a chance to try this but it sounds like it would work.

Answer (score 2):

if your android has search button then you are lucky first hard reset your android(learn how to hard reset your mobile) after the mobile started running hit search button and search the app 'settings' then turn bluetooth on and select discoverable or visible then share any launcher (like smart launcher) from other android to your mobile then install it and enjoy

Comment: I can't try this out because the problem is already solved for me, but I'll upvote it because it sounds like it would work.

Answer (score 1):

Go into Recovery Mode (try turning off the phone and do not turn it on but press and hold the home button the volume up button and then hold the power button along with it).  You need to do a Factory Reset from there and then reboot the phone.

Comment: I tried that immediately. It didn't help. And in fact it was the only way that it would boot at all.

Answer (score 0):

Push and install a launcher app to your Android device from http://play.google.com (PC).

Comment: The question asks *how* to do this, not *whether* to do it.

Comment: @betherwisser Yes, it's *How to* my dear (navigating you on the website would be dumb). It's much much simpler and reliable than accepted answer.

Comment: > I can't open the Play store, can't open anything except those that use voice commands: e-mail, text, phone, maps, navigation, and note to self.

Comment: @betherwisser I said do it from **PC** or other device.

Comment: "Cannot use ADB or put it in debug mode..." so how would I do it from a PC or other device?